# Where is the code that uploads media in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to call an external API when the user upload a media file. The media that is uploaded will be sent to the API too.

Which code in the WordPress that I could modify for the purpose?

Comment: you can use hook and call api when media uploaded....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload Media from your WordPress admin dashboard, `wp_handle_upload` is called once for each file the user specified. `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` is an admin filter that is called by the wp_handle_upload function. The single parameter, $file, represent a single element of the `$_FILES` array. The `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` provides you with an opportunity to examine or alter the filename before the file is moved to its final location.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );

function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
    //call your api here
    $file['name'] = 'wordpress-is-awesome-' . $file['name'];
    return $file;
}
```

Using this, in conjunction with the upload_dir, you can dynamically determine which directory to upload to, based on the files you upload. [check link here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter) or [stack site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53753/saving-media-which-hook-is-fired)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But it doesn't work, I tried to put `header('Location: https://google.com');` too for testing but it doesn't do anything

Comment: you can use var_dump($file); and put code in functions.php file

Comment: I tried adding this to functions.php `    add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter');

    function custom_upload_filter( $file ) {
        var_dump($file);
        return $file;
    }
` but I got `An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.`

Comment: put exit after var_dump() and enable error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter');

function custom_upload_filter( $file ) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    var_dump($file);
    exit;
}

still doesn't work...

Comment: the `$file['name'] = 'wordpress-is-awesome-' . $file['name'];` does work, but I don't know what object `$file` is, how can I see it (with var_dump or something)?

Comment: your file in $file['tmp_name'] modify or copy whereever you want...check link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168161/modifying-an-uploaded-image-with-wp-get-image-editor-and-wp-handle-upload-pre

Comment: The `var_dump` didn't work since it will break the filter (so does `echo`). but your answer showed the filter, so thanks!